# Java OOP - Issue with Modelling in simple example (Polymorphism). Composition or Inheritance?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I am trying to model some system in Java (OOP), but I'll use a simpler example to explain the problem I'm running into (which I believe is to do with Polymorphism and/or Inheritence). Though I have a feeling that the solution may be to do with Composition.

Say simply we have **Animal**, **Species**, **Bird** and **Pigeon**. The current relationship I have is:

- **Pigeon** implements/extends **Animal**, **Bird** (Pigeon is an animal and a bird)
- **Bird** implements/extends **Species** (A bird is a species)

Though keep in mind that this design should be extendable to include more **Animals** and **Species**.

I want to do the following:

1. For a `List<Animal>`, I want to be able to add `Pigeon` (and other animals) only but not `Species` or `Bird`. This is satisfied.
2. For a `List<Bird>`, I want to be able to add `Pigeon` (and other birds) only. This is satisfied.
3. However, for a `List<Species>`, I want to be able to add `Bird` (and other species) only; however, by **polymorphism** of this design, I'm able to add `Pigeon` too which is undesirable (I want it such that **Pigeon** is not a **Species** in this example).

I never understood this entirely, but I believe this runs into the issues with inheritence that I've heard so much about. I hope I've explained the example in sufficient detail, but if anyone has any suggestions as to how to model this at all (with abstract classes, interfaces, composition, design patterns, anything), that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: If Pigeon extends Bird, and Bird extends Species, Pigeon *is* a Species. Parent classes of parent classes are also parent classes of their subclasses' subclasses'.

Comment: Yes, I understand, which is the problem currently I believe. I'm wondering if there's a way to model it such that Pigeon is not a Species while meeting the other requirements.

Comment: Not as long as Bird is a Species, unless Pigeon is not a Bird.

Comment: I think this won't be achievable without composition. You need to decouple some stuff here. have you thought about having Pigeon implement Animal only (so not Bird) and composing it with a Species object such as Bird ?

Comment: That is exactly what just crossed my mind just then and I'm thinking about it right now with the actual system I'm trying to model. I'm just wondering how I would accomplish a list of Species in this case. Would I instantiate and create the list of species at the start and then reference the object in the list for each animal in that case?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea if you have a large number of Animal to instantiate. I think you can also get away with a "unique" Species instance for each Animal you are creating too. In any case you will probably benefit from making a factory to handle the instantiation complexity that composition adds.

Answer (score 1):

I'll change it like this choosing one between the red or blue relation :

[image]

The second point is not satisfied but you could avoid it using composition.